# Batch command within .py Pyinstaller causing error

Tags: python-2.7, batch-file, pyinstaller, simplehttpserver

I'm creating a standalone/portable exe via pyinstaller that can be run from a PC without python.  The problem I'm having is the batch command I'm using within the .py file to start SimpleHTTPServer and serve to a specific directory.  This code (batch command):

```
os.chdir('c:\MC\log')
os.system('cmd /c start python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080')
```

It errors because of the direct reference to "python" in the command. My question is how can I include this batch command without referencing python OR is there another method to start SimpleHTTPServer and serve to a specific directory?

Comment: Is the directory containing `python.exe` in your system's and/or user's `PATH` variable?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, no.  The intent is to be able to run this on a PC that does not have Python installed.  Do I have to tell Pyinstaller to include the python.exe in some way, for reference?  Or is there simply another command I can apply to start SimpleHTTPServer serving to a specific directory?